# there is my session tracking programme in JSP but it is showing error while it is correct as same as in tutorialspoint.com

Tags: java, html, jsp, session

```
<%@page import="java.io.*,java.util.*"%><% //get session creation time  Date createTime=new Date(session.getCreationTime());
    //get last Access time
    Date lastAccessTime=new Date(session.getLastAccessedTime());    
    String title="welcome to my website";    
    Integer visitCount=new Integer(0);    
    String visitCountKey=new String("visitCount");    
    String userIDkey=new        
    String("userID");    
    String userID=new String("ABCD");
    //check if this is a new comer on your web page
    if(session.isNew()){    
      title="welcome to our website";    
      session.setAttribute(userIDkey,userID);    
      session.setAttribute(visitCountKey,visitCount);    
    }    
  visitCount=(Integer)session.getAttribute(visitCountKey);    
  visitCount=visitCount+1;    
  userID=(String)session.getAttribute(userIDkey);
  session.setAttribute(visitCountKey,visitCount);    %>

<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 3.2 Final//EN">
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
            <title>JSP Page</title>
        </head>
        <body>
            <h1>SESSION TRACKING</h1>
            <table border="1" align="center">
                <tr bgcolor="#949494"        
                    <th>Session Info</th>
                    <th>Value</th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>id</td>
                    <td><% out.print(session.getId());%>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Creation time</td>
                    <td><% out.print(createTime); %>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>time of last access</td>
                    <td><% out.print(lastAccessTime);%>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>USER ID</td>
                    <td><% out.print(userID);%>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>number of visits</td>
                    <td><% out.print(visitCount);%    
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Please format the codes to make it readable.

Comment: So what is your question? What errors do you get while running the above code? Reena